# UITableView with multi(+ 10) custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a question in coding style.
In Details View (Image reference as below) 
[image]

Apply UITableView For the whole pages and add custom UITableViewCell for each row(this design might have 12 custom UITableViewCells for each indexpath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
  if(indexPath.row == 0){
    load custom cell for row 0 ( which is image)
  } else if(indexPath.row == 1){
     load custom cell for row 1 ( which is text and graph)

 }  else if(indexPath.row == 2){
      load custom cell for row 2 ( which is UICollectionview)

  }  else if(indexPath.row == 3){
      load custom cell for row 3 ( which is UIScrollview with images)

  } else if(indexPath.row == 4){
     load custom cell for row 4 ( which is UIPicker or anything else)

  }//and so on until indexPath.row == 11
}
```

This is really the right way to do UITableView with multi custom in this Controller? and you have to implement if-else in DidSelectRowAtPath again .Personally, It's looks so weird with the code multiple if-else and the concept of UITableView is designed for this? How about UIScrollview?

In theory, this looks promising with the dequeue stuff, it's make this details controller very efficient for memory? I just want to learn the right way to use UITableView. If most people doing similar to this, I have to accept it and use it also

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer - YES!